# Authenticate in ASP.Net Core using API-Token

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, bearer-token

I am currently using JwtBearer as the authentication scheme, meaning users have to log in using their username and password and receive a token which authenticates them for a while.

Now I need to make requests to the API from another system, which should not have to need to login every time the bearer token runs out of time. Is there a way to send a secret universal token with every request the other system has to make so that it does not need to authenticate?

I tried setting up another bearer login using only a token, but that was a dumb idea since it still needs to renew every now and then.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, for normal web api which protect by some identity provider, you need to get the token from the identity provider(Like Azure AD) and use that token access that web api process.

The token is stored inside the cookie for that identity provider url and then we could use that cookie value to get it and use it to access all the web api service.

For the client which let the user to type-in the username and password, it could receive the identity provider(AAD) server returned token and the client could decide store the token or else to avoid user login multiple time.

This storing token action is based on different client and is not consider by the Identity provider or the web api service provider.

In my opinion, you just need to make sure all the web api using the same JWT authentication configuration. About how to store the token is consider by the client-side, normally, this token is stored inside the browser cookie.

Comment: Thats not exactly what im looking for. I would like to add the possiblity to, instead of logging in with username/password, to provide a static token (set in code by me) which allows usage of the api without logging in everytime, like a permanent bearer token

Comment: The thing is how long this token will exist? If this token is always exist, this is also not security.

Comment: I am aware of that, but that's not a problem in the given case, since the token only gets limited access to the api. I figured out that 10 years is the maximum, so I'll have to roll with that, I guess.